# Function always returning true in Javascript ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which checks if comments author is current or not.This function returns true or false.

I also have function which checks result of this function and the problem is result function always returns true.

Any suggestions please?

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => {
  return comments.filter((item: any): boolean => {
    if (item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};

const checkCommentAuthorResult = (): any => {
  let checkResult = checkCommentAuthor();
  if (checkResult) {
    return <IsCommentAuthor / > ;
  } else {
    return <IsNotCommentAuthor / > ;
  }
};

return checkCommentAuthorResult();
};
```

Comment: might be your item does not have username property so `item.username` is undefined and `localStorage.getItem("username")` is also undefined

Comment: You're using `filter()`, which means your comments array changes into a smaller array. So if you have five comments, and two are by the author, the function returns an array of two comments, not true or false. An array is truthy, so it always returns true. I'm also wondering how exactly this is supposed to work in general: shouldn't you check whether the user is the author for each comment individually?

Comment: @ChrisG could you tell me how to fix it or which method to use please ?

Comment: I tried to use map but got same result

Comment: try `let checkResult = checkCommentAuthor()[0]`

Comment: `<IsCommentAuthor />` sounds like something you would display for each comment, so shouldn't you rather check `comment.username === loggedInUser` or something inside the comment rendering loop?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do,item.username is username of comment and localstorage.getIem('username') is username of logged in user

Comment: Please show us the `.map()` part of the JSX that renders the comments. Because you are trying to solve a problem you don't have in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` returns an array, which is always truthy, even if it's empty. You can simplify this a bit using `some` instead, which returns `true` if at least one item matches:

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => {
  return comments.some((item: any): boolean => {
    if (item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

You also don't need this `if`/`else` or return type since this already has a boolean equality check:

```
const checkCommentAuthor = () => {
  return comments.some(
    (item: any) => item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")
  );
};
```

Finally, you can simplify the JSX with a ternary:

```
const checkCommentAuthorResult = () => {
  let Result = checkCommentAuthor() ? IsCommentAuthor : IsNotCommentAuthor;
  return <Result />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help,Your answer is the closest to the result I want to get.Now I get the following problem.I guess its because of the `some` method.If one comment belongs to the user whole result is changing to the true.Is there any other method which would fix my problem?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted. What's the issue and what results do you want specifically?

Comment: OP actually has a different problem; see my comments below their question.

Answer (score 3):

The `Array.filter()` function [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array. So saying every check returns `false` u get an empty array, and an array (empty or not) translates always to `true`.

This would be better:

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => {
  return comments.filter((item: any): boolean => {
    if (item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }).length > 0; // check on length
};
```

EDIT:
And a little refactoring

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => 
  comments.filter((item: any): boolean => 
    item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")
  ).length > 0; // check on length
```

Comment: There's a function that already does this: [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your filter function to the following:

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): any => {
  return comments.filter((item: any): any => {
    item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")
  });
};
```

and then check if filtered array is empty

```
if (checkResult.length > 0) {
```

Comment: the return type of `checkCommentAuthor ` is still wrong

Comment: @Greedo correct, i forgot it is typescript. changed it to `any`

Answer (score 2):

your function can be simplified (many parts are useless/not needed).
As the others said too, `Array.filter()` returns an array with all the element that match to true to the filter function body. In case of no match, `[]` is returned.

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => {
  return comments.filter((item) => item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")).length > 0;
};

const checkCommentAuthorResult = (): any => {
  return checkCommentAuthor() ? <IsCommentAuthor / > : <IsNotCommentAuthor / > ;
};

checkCommentAuthorResult();
```